# Sorting a dropdown list in C#

Tags: c#, sql, list, drop-down-menu

I acquired this code from someone and need to organize the list alphabetically.  I tried to add an `ORDER BY` at the end of the `Select` but it actually makes the whole list empty.  I then tried adding additional code to sort it after the list is retrieved, still nothing. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
public void FillDropdowns()
{
    SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
    string queryText = "SELECT  JobTitle1,Department,PracticeArea,Offices from Scope()  WHERE \"SCOPE\" = 'People'  AND DisplayInDirectory = 'Include'";//,SecondaryOfficeLocationFROM  Scope()  WHERE \"SCOPE\" = 'People' " + finalquery + " AND DisplayInDirectory = 'Include' ";//,SecondaryOfficeLocation
    FullTextSqlQuery query1 = new FullTextSqlQuery(site);
    query1.QueryText = queryText;
    query1.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
    query1.RowLimit = 1000;
    ResultTableCollection resultTables = query1.Execute();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (resultTables.Count > 0)
    {
        ResultTable relevantResults = resultTables[ResultType.RelevantResults];
        dt.Load(relevantResults, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
    }

    int j = dt.Rows.Count;
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    ddldept.DataSource = dv.ToTable(true, "Department");
    ddldept.DataTextField = "Department";
    ddldept.DataValueField = "Department";
    ddldept.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select department", "select department"));
    ddldept.DataBind();

    ddlpractice.DataSource = dv.ToTable(true, "PracticeArea");
    ddlpractice.DataTextField = "PracticeArea";
    ddlpractice.DataValueField = "PracticeArea";
    ddlpractice.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select practiceArea", "select practiceArea"));
    ddlpractice.DataBind();

    ddltitle.DataSource = dv.ToTable(true, "JobTitle1");
    ddltitle.DataTextField = "JobTitle1";
    ddltitle.DataValueField = "JobTitle1";
    ddltitle.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select title", "select title"));
    ddltitle.DataBind();

    ddlOffice.DataSource = dv.ToTable(true, "Offices");
    ddlOffice.DataTextField = "Offices";
    ddlOffice.DataValueField = "Offices";
    ddlOffice.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select offices", "select offices"));
    ddlOffice.DataBind();

}
```

EDIT:  Here is where I added the `ORDER BY`:

```
string queryText = "SELECT  JobTitle1,Department,PracticeArea,Offices from Scope()  WHERE     \"SCOPE\" = 'People'  AND DisplayInDirectory = 'Include' ORDER BY Department ASC";
```

Comment: Apply the order by to your query, not your code.

Comment: That is the first thing I tried.  I added the ORDER BY to the end of the query, but it made the whole list disappear.

Comment: Can you show where you added the ORDER BY exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited my post with where I put the ORDER BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few options:

1. Add the `order by` within your SQL Statement
2. Sort the dataview

Example:

```
DataTable table = dataSet.Tables["TableName"];
DataView view = table.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "Criteria";
```